# TinyMCE editor files in MOODLE 2.7

Tags: tinymce, moodle

In **MOODLE** I am using the **tinyMCE editor**. Here a button for **insert special characters** are available. This is build in button for `tinyMCE`. The image of the button is given below..

[image]

I have to customise this button function by adding some more symbols extra. But I can't find the file to edit. Which file is contains the functions of `insert special character` button. And where it resides. I look the **moodle/lib/editor/tinymce** directory but I can't find the necessary files. Please any one help me to find...

I am using **moodle 2.7** version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbols are in this file

```
/lib/editor/tinymce/tiny_mce/3.5.8/themes/advanced/js/charmap.js
```